# Nuxt / Vue redirect if vuex property is undefind not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, router

I got a nuxt app running which has an account page. This account page uses mapState computed properties for the user. User data is used in the account page template as well as its child components via props.

Whenever I start the app by going to myurl/account I get "can not read property x of undefined". Its obvious to me, as there is no logged in user when I go right away to /account.

I tried to push the routes back to the /login page within the created() hook of the account page, but its not working. I still get the same error.

How to deal with users trying to access a page before a property used by the template is set? The created hook logs only server side, not in the dev tools of chrome. Shouldnt this.$router.push("login") work?

**ACCOUNT PAGE**

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="px-0 py-0 mt-12">
    <v-row>
      <accountheader :user="user" :company="company" />
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  transitions: "page",
  computed: {
    ...mapState("user", {
      company: (state) => state.company,
      user: (state) => state.user,
    }),
  },
  head: {
    title: "ACCOUNT",
    meta: [
      {
        hid: "description",
        name: "description",
        content: "account page",
      },
    ],
  },
  created() {
    if (this.user === undefined) {
      this.$router.push("/login");
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get arround this myself by implementing a middleware in the page file itself like so. In case anyone runs into the same issue.

**Solution**

`middleware({ store, redirect }) { // If the user is not authenticated if (store.state.user.user === undefined) { return redirect("/login"); } },`